# Loop within return statement or outside the return statement of a functional component?

Tags: reactjs

There are two ways to render dynamic jsx elements

This could be loop or conditional statements.

Example
One way to do this:

```
function DisplayCollections() {
  return <>
    {collections.map((collection, index) => {
    return (
      <option value={collection.id} key={index}>
        {collection.name}
      </option>
    )};
  </>
}
```

Another way to do the same:

```
function DisplayCollections() {
  const collections = collections.map((collection, index) => {
    return (
      <option value={collection.id} key={index}>
        {collection.name}
      </option>
    );
  });
  return {collections}
}
```

Ofcourse, the examples are basic. But I hope you understand where this question is coming from.

What is the best way to do something like? Or when do you do one over the other?

Comment: The second example is not valid, I expect you intended to return `[collections]` i.e wrap it in an array, or even better just return `collections` or directly `collections.map`. The second example is unnecessarily verbose IMO and I have not seen it used in the wild. Assigning fragments of JSX to variables to clean up the return statement of larger components is somewhat common.

Answer (score 0):

```
function DisplayCollections() {
  return <>
    {collections.map((collection, index) =>(
      <option value={collection.id} key={index}>
        {collection.name}
      </option>
    )
  </>
}
```

this is best way to use!